# How can I change a python variable from a Visual Studio program?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a Windows Form program in Visual Studio that can send emails from a basic GUI.

For example I have `email_message = input("Message: ")` in my `python` script. Could I change the input of `email_message` from a text box on my Windows Form Program?

Comment: Can you explain your situation a bit more? How and why are you using both Python and Windows Forms? 
You could use just one... so what's the reason for putting them together?
Have you looked at Python-based GUIs instead of Windows Forms, or handling the input without Python?
(Also, put code `tags` (back ticks) around your Python code in your question to improve readability.)

Comment: I'm able to made a "modern UI" relatively easy using Windows Forms, but not with Python. Every Python GUI toolkit I use it looks quite dated.